# Upper Bound and Lower Bound is equal to 0.0 in Cplex (In cplex java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, cplex

I have a loop going on in which sometime **UpperBound** and Lower Bound are 0.0
At that time i dont want to execute below line.

```
Test[index]=cplex.numVar(0.0, upperBound);
```

I can skip that but in **Test[index]** null will be saved because of which next method which is having below code will give null pointer exception.

```
constraint.addTerm(RezCapZZ[index ], 1);
```

How can i proceed without executing UB and LB equal to 0.0 . Need to find a way so that second method does not throw null pointer exception.

Why I am doing this because we need to save memory of **cplex** unnecessary calculation of 0.

1st Method:

```
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                    for (int oc = 0; oc < 3; oc++) {
                        for(int dc=0; dc < 3 ;dc++){
                                        UB=  0.0;
                                        int index = y*3*3*3 + r*3*3 + oc*3 + dc;
                                        Test[index]  = cplex.numVar(0.0, UB);
                                        System.out.println("Value of Test is : " + Test[index]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here Test[index] is of type **IloNumVar [] Test =  new IloNumVar [3*3*3*3];**

2nd Method:

```
for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                                for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                                    for(int oc=0; oc< 3 ; oc++){
                                        index =  l*3*3*3 + y*3*3 + r*3 + oc;

                                        **constraint.addTerm(Test[index ], 1);**

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Here constraint is  **IloLinearNumExpr constraint = cplex.linearNumExpr();**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check in your first method:

```
if( 0.0 == UB || 0.0 == UB ) {
    continue;
}
```

and add a check in your second method:

```
if( null == Test[index] ) {
   continue;
}
```

or

Comment: Yes, this will skip the first method UB and LB calcluation but in 2nd method there will be a nullPointerException because Test[index] is null now for those where UB == LB == 0.0... I am stucked in 2nd method...

Comment: It looks like your first method, seeds the `Test` array - is that right? If so, you need to decide what the "Right Thing" to do is when that's zero - perhaps just continue as I've edited my answer to also provide.